Does GCC guarantee size-matched accesses?
I'm not really sure how to ask this question succinctly, so I apologize if this is already asked and answered.
I am working on an ARM platform with a 32-bit pseudo-register access to a peripheral FIFO.  Depending on the size of the read or write, a variable number of bytes are removed or added to the FIFO.
I wrote the following C code to perform a 16-bit (halfword) read:
a_u16_var = *(uint16_t*)&FIFO_REG;
and confirmed that it indeed resulted in an ldrh opcode in the object file.
Is this guaranteed?  If I follow the same pattern for uint32_t and uint8_t, can I depend on the compiler generating ldr/str and ldrb/strb, respectively?  If not, what's the best way to ensure the right size access?  Inline assembly?
EDIT: More platform specifics:

Core: ARM Cortex-M33 (STM32H563ZI to be really specific)
Compiler: GNU arm-none-eabi-* version 11.3.1 (GNU Tools for STM32 11.3)
OS: FreeRTOS, if that counts


In general, no you can't rely on that - see What is the strict aliasing rule?  If you have to do a cast via address like that, you're almost certainly violating strict aliasing and invoking undefined behavior.  But systems and compilers designed to provide things like FIFO_REG probably provide extensions to the C language so they can reliably use such functionality.  You'd need to provide exact details of your platform for anyone to give you an accurate answer - OS (if any), hardware, and compiler.

While this 'strict aliasing' link is true.  Follow one rule: wrap this behaviour somewhere.  There is the 'C' language and all it beholds, then there is behaviour of actual hardware.  On some systems, you may have a cache, but this type of memory is definitely not cacheable.  Depending on compiler optimizations, it may eliminate redundant stores to the same address.  If you wrap it in one place versus littering the entire code base, it is easier to fix things (on an OS, hardware, compiler or general understanding of the universe update).

Marking the type volatile is your best bet (that's what the keyword is designed for). Though the standard doesn't guarantee you anything, only a completely broken or deliberately evil implementation would behave contrary to your expectations. Such implementation don't tend to stick around.

I added the gcc tag because it is mentioned in your title and you definitely cannot design code to do this correctly using the C standard alone. It requires compilers-specific features. Among other things, you should use -fno-strict-aliasing to tell the compiler the program may not be obeying the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. You should add the compiler version you are using.

@n.m.couldbeanAI - You mean such as *(volatile uint16_t *)...?  FIFO_REG itself is defined as a volatile uint32_t already.

@BrianA.Henning Yes, like that.

@BrianA.Henning: Whether FIFO_REG is defined with volatile or not is irrelevant because (uint 16_t *) converts the address to a pointer to a non-volatile type, and then the semantics of * (uint16_t *) &FIFO_REG are to access a non-volatile object.

Compliers typically dont make guarantees like that, but volatile in the pointer declaration should help.  Suggest you can write a 2 line assembly function to ensure you're getting what you want.

FWIW the linux kernel does not rely on volatile on ARM, using accessors with inline asm instead. Notice in particular the memory barrier in the writew and readw macros

"FIFO_REG itself is defined as a volatile uint32_t already" But then (uint16_t*) cast casts volatility away. You probably should have received a warning about it.

With volatile, yes, GCC will try to use only a single access of width matching the type of the volatile access, if it's a size the machine can do natively.
I don't remember where I read this; it's not in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html (which is mostly about what counts as a volatile access, and whether there's a separate read when you do tricky stuff like x = volatile_var = y;)
Otherwise no, zero guarantee, and you can construct test cases that tempt GCC into doing a single wider access, or accessing just the low or high byte for example, IIRC something like var &= 0xFF will get it to do a zero-extending byte load instead of half-word and separate zero-extend.  And Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes has another counter-example where it can use stp of a pair of 32-bit halves for non-volative, which isn't guaranteed to be a single 64-bit atomic access before ARMv8.4.  Using volatile uint64_t makes it a single access that's safe for e.g. the Linux kernel to roll its own atomics.

For MMIO you definitely want volatile anyway!!  But you're casting to a pointer-to-plain-uint16, not pointer-to-volatile, so that's bad.
a_u16_var = *(volatile uint16_t*)&FIFO_REG;
// should be safe in GNU C for what you're looking for

The rules surrounding volatile accesses should be sufficient that you don't need -fno-strict-aliasing (which was mentioned in comments).  Volatile accesses can't reorder (at compile time) with other volatile accesses, and the compiler doesn't assume anything about the value loaded or stored.  As long as all your accesses to the MMIO register are volatile, there aren't any assumptions GCC can be making.

This handles some compiler issues.  Claims here are that FreeRTOS is non-SMP.  There are points there that a compiler memory barrier could be needed in some cases.  asm volatile ("" ::: "memory").  Ie, sometimes for interrupts and mainline, forcing an access order can be important.  See for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146098/reordering-of-access-to-multiple-volatile-variables-in-c  To be complete, the OP maybe concerned/aware with/of this nuance.
